# Reconstructing a string from random samples

Tags: ds.algorithms

What is known about the following problem?

> Reconstruct a string $\sigma$ of known length $n$ over a known
>   alphabet $\Sigma$ from a collection of uniformly and independently
>   chosen $k$-long subsequences of $\sigma$ where $k$ is fixed between
>   $0$ and $n$.

*Recall that a $k$-long subsequence of $\sigma=\langle \sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n\rangle$ is a sequence $\langle \sigma_{\varphi(1)},\dots,\sigma_{\varphi(k)}\rangle$ where $\varphi$ is an increasing function from $\{1,\ldots,k\}$ to $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.*

Comment: I think that it is a variant of the problem of reconstructing strings from random traces (in which every trace have the same length $t$); see for example [this paper](http://www.maths.lse.ac.uk/Personal/batu/papers/delch.pdf)

Comment: Is it a single random sample, as seems to be written, but makes no sense to me, or a large enough collection of random samples? CC @D.W.

Comment: Is it intentional that the definition of subsequence allows φ to be non-decreasing instead of increasing?  According to the current definition (Revision 6), “ccc” is a subsequence of “abcde”.

Comment: You're right @Tsuyoshi Ito, it should be increasing.

Comment: Cross-posted to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/185500

Comment: It looks like this question was [answered](http://mathoverflow.net/a/185520/8239) on MO, so I am closing this version.